# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) During Pause From Echo

Tags: php, html, json, api

I know there's a lot of other questions similar to this one, but I couldn't find any that would apply to my current situation. Here's my code snippet:

```
<?php

            foreach ($configs->servernames as $key => $servertitle) {

                $serverip =  $configs->serverips[$key];
                $serverport =  $configs->serverports[$key];

                //Server Info Getter
                    $json = file_get_contents('https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=' . $serverip . '&port=' . $serverport);
                    $data = json_decode($json,true);

                    $onlinestatus = $data['online'];
                    echo $onlinestatus;

                        if ($onlinestatus == 1) {

                            echo 'check_circle';

                        }
                        else {
                            echo 'cancel';
                        }

                echo '

                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">'. 
                        //Online or offline response
                            if ($onlinestatus == 1) {

                                echo 'check_circle';

                            }
                            else {

                                echo 'cancel';

                            }
                         .'</i>'. $serverip .'</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Server Info & Status</p></div>
                </li>

                ';
                //check_circle is the check icon
            } //$servertitle var
        ?>
```

I also looked for any missing semicolons or any tags that I might've left open. I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that I'm pausing the echo and THEN using an if statement.

Here's my issue:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\gitrepos\Server-Status\web\index.php on line 38

Also, the EXACT SAME if statement works outside of the echo pause, as seen above it.

Comment: Your observations were correct. You can't just use an if statement inside a concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for marking the duplicate, the dupe's solution worked! :D <3 M8!